# Writing FAT32 image file to a RAW partition

Tags: filesystems, fat32

Is it possible to write a FAT32 image file to a partition, like a second partition, programmaticaly?

Comment: I think he wants to know if the pointers in the file system are relative (to the beginning of the partition) or absolute. And then he will have to reattach it to the Partition Table.

Comment: What i want to is create and FAT32 image and copy some files into it. And then copy this image to another HDD as an seperate partition. 
What is the best way of doing this? Can i create and fat32 image like a zip /rar file? I have to do all this things in Win7

Comment: Programmatically as in you want to program something yourself ?  Using other tools this is certainly possible and FAT is relative to the partition start (not absolute, so the FAT File System itself doesn't need to be edited)

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm did you try using linux dd???
boot with a liveCD ([maybe this one](http://www.sysresccd.org/))an then $ dd if=/image/fat32/file of=/dev/other/partition

Comment: I want to do it on Windows without any external tool or command.